# Updating height_ratios of gridspec multiplot after initial creation

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to change the height ratios of my stacked triple plot after it has been created using the `.set_height_ratios()` method of a `GridSpec` object. The reason I need this is that I have a method in my class, which multiplies data by a certain factor to make it "more visible" in a certain range (start, end, factor). Once this multiplication has been performed, the height ratios of my plot need to update so that the top axes, which contains experimental and calculated data has the same scale as the third axes, which contains the difference between the experimental and calculated data. This is an example of what I am creating right now:

[image: Example plot with cut off difference peak (green)]

As you can see, if the difference is multiplied by the factor, and it maintains the same scale as ax1, which contains the experimental/calculated data, the marked peak will be cut off, since the current heigth ratio can no longer accomodate the full peak, if the scales of ax1 and ax3 are identical (meaning, same amount of pixels per ax units)

So what I tried to do is to use the `set_height_ratios()` method to increase the height ratio of ax3 (bottom) if a multiplication has been performed, so that it can still fully accomodate the cut off peak. But I have found out that this only works, if I use `constrained_layout=True` and `plt.tight_layout()`.

GitHub Issue: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8434

I cannot use those options, because it completely breaks my multiplot and doesn't function with `plt.adjust_subplots(hspace=0)`.

Here's some example code that shows how updating the height ratios only works with `constrained_layout` and `plt.tight_layout()`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 4), constrained_layout=False) # set this to true
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(3, 1, height_ratios=[1,1,1])

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[2])

ax1.plot([1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1], label='Subplot 1')
ax2.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], label='Subplot 2')
ax3.plot([1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 2], label='Subplot 3')


print("Original height ratios:", gs.get_height_ratios())

new_height_ratios = [5, 1, 1]
gs.set_height_ratios(new_height_ratios)

print("Updated height ratios:", gs.get_height_ratios())

# plt.tight_layout() # uncomment this

plt.show()
```

My actual code is a bit long and so I didn't want to put it all in here, but I have a github repository that contains all the relevant files [here](https://github.com/p3rAsperaAdAstra/Pawley-Fit-Plot) if you're intersted in the whole thing.

My question is: Can I get this to work without `constrained_layout` and `plt.tight_layout`?

EDIT: I have managed to get it working by just doing all the multiplications first before creating the figure/GridSpec object. But  I would still like to know if it isn't possible to update the height ratios without using the aforementioned options.

Comment: No, this will not work without moving the axes somehow.  `constrained_layout` and `tight_layout` move the axes.  You will have to position them yourself using `ax1.set_position()`

Comment: will you be making a small example of how to use `ax.set_position()` or should I just close this issue?